# OpenVPN GUI does not run; error opening registry for reading HKLM\SOFTWARE\OpenVPN

Tags: openvpn, portable-apps

I'm trying to run OpenVPN as a portable application and to that effect have installed it on a Windows 7 machine, copied the files to another Windows 7 machine and manually restored the registry settings using a .reg file. Whenever I try to run OpenVPN GUI I get the following error:

> Error opening registry for reading HKLM\SOFTWARE\OpenVPN

I have verified that the key mentioned is indeed in the registry at the correct location with the correct values yet the GUI still complains. I've also tried running the GUI as an administrator (I'm logged in as an administrator) and changing the compatibility modes but nothing helped.

If I use OpenVPN Portable (`OpenVPNPortable_1.6.6.paf.exe`) it has the same problem.

Any ideas how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You have to re-route it through the VFR mainframe. Either your application has been corrupted by the existing server or you have affected the registry through a different channel- PKN, maybe, could be the JumbleBlok net system- but whichever is the case, you're still going to need to manually alter the channel course.

Try this, it'll hopefully make things easier for you when working with the code:

> http://www.windowssevenforums.net/forums/topic-vpn/portable-system-transferral-guide/app-soft.htm

It'll help you redirect the proxy drive and use the OPICS system to get your app back on track.

Answer (score -1):

open control panel and go to administrator tools. From there go to registry editor, when that opens go to hkey_current_user which should be one of the first files( for me it's the second one). Next in that file go down to the software file delete the program that's giving you the issue and then reinstall and that should fix this issue for this and other programs with similar issue. I hope this helps as the error i had was this (open vpn gui error opening registry for reading (HKLM\softeware\openvpn). open vpn is probably not installed) and this fixed it, given i changed drived and the software was on the one i was overriding this gui stayed and gave me this issue for whatever reason and this is how i had to fix the issue.
have a great day and good luck to anyone who reads this.

Comment: Ummmm nope. First, this question is 10 years old. Second, you're giving general and unspecific advice to delete registry keys without clearly listing which keys to delete and why. It is never a good idea to go into the registry and delete keys that vaguely resemble the name of the software you're having trouble with.