# Sophos SSL VPN Client Uninstall - Error opening registry for reading (HKLM\SOFTWARE\OpenVPN)

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, openvpn, sophos

After uninstalling **Sophos SSL VPN Client**, windows gives the error message at start up:
[image]

```
---------------------------
Sophos SSL VPN Client
---------------------------
Error opening registry for reading (HKLM\SOFTWARE\OpenVPN).
OpenVPN is probably not installed
```

I have checked windows **Registry**:

```
HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
```

And the StartUp folders:

```
shell:common startup
%PROGRAMDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp 

shell:startup
%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
```

**Task Manager** startup section also checked.

There is a similar questions [here](https://superuser.com/questions/253927/openvpn-gui-does-not-run-error-opening-registry-for-reading-hklm-software-openv#), with an insufficient answer.

Where can I find the settings that starts up **Sophos SSL VPN Client**, so that it can be removed and windows starts without displaying this error message?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check **Task Scheduler**, you will probably find that **Sophos VPN Client** starts from there.

Or, try [Autoruns](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns) for **Windows** from **Sysinternals**

[image]